# Rending of 1-pixel thin line with AndEngine and Box2D

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I create a PhysicsWorld in the following manner:

```
this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 8, 1);
```

And I create a line in the following manner:

```
final Line line = new Line(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getX()+object.getWidth(), object.getY()+object.getHeight());
final FixtureDef lineFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, line, lineFixtureDef);
line.setVisible(true);
mScene.attachChild(line);
```

This should allow for collisions on a one-pixel bar, but is not producing the desired effect.  Beneath the bar there are at least several pixels, and to the left, there are several pixels, the height and right-side are fine.

I have also tested this with a rectangle and am having the same problem.

Comment: Hi user2080866, may I ask what object is colliding with this line? For example if you have a ball sprite with a box body and rotation enabled you may find that if the body's corner collides with the line you may have a gap between your ball sprite and the line, (where the body's corner is). Also I found collisions can be 'twitchy' with low SPS. Have you tried increaing this to say 150? i.e., this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(150, ...

Comment: he is a player sprite has set mPlayerBody   mPlayerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, mplayer, BodyType.DynamicBody, playerFixtureDef);
  this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mplayer, mPlayerBody, true, false){

Comment: i try to 150, it's same. gap of several pixels

Comment: Same problem if the line is vertical, in the bottom of the line is not drawn but several gap pixels or My character can not go

Comment: Hi, so it's a box body, what is mplayer? Is it a Sprite, Animated Sprite.... Could you check your image, does it have access alpha pixels say on the top and right edges? If it is an animated sprite how much gap is there in between the sprite columns and rows on your sprite sheet? - If there is excess these alpha gaps could be included when the image is 'divided up'. Also you are using box body, what is the sprite itself? If it is a ball use circle body or if it is irregular in shape and you want accurate collisions use polygon body. I have good functions for the latter I can provide.

Comment: mplayer is a animate sprite controlling by onControlChange, player.png in folder gfx in andengine example, how to remedy this?

Comment: this corresponds well to the difference

Comment: it was good that, I've remove the border of picture and it's ok, very thanks for your HELP !

Comment: No worries, I had tested your code thus far and it workedg fine which lead me to suspect your image used in your sprite. Glad I could help! I will put this in an answer for easy reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're saying is the line is rendering at the wrong location.  You're getting the line location from the location of Object.  My guess is that you're expecting the line to render from the center of "object" but instead it's rendering from the top-left corner of object.  That's the expected and desired behavior in AndEngine.  If you want it to render from the center, you need to calculate the center location of the object, not just take the X & Y.

Relatedly, you should probably not be thinking in pixels, but in scene coordinates.  I assume when you say "pixels," you're using that as a shorthand for scene coordinates, but if not, be aware that they're not the same thing.

Comment: new Line is starting from x from y Width and Height, or center must be in the function New Line ?

Comment: if I put on true "line.setVisible(true)" the line, however, are well drawn in the correct location but several gap pixels or My character can not go in the bottom and in the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you have these issues, check the following,

Check your image, does it have access alpha pixels around the edges?

If it is an animated sprite how much gap is there in between the sprite columns and rows on your sprite sheet? - If there is excess these alpha gaps could be included when the image is 'divided up'.

Also if you are using box body, what is the sprite itself? If it is a ball use circle body or if it is irregular in shape and you want more accurate collisions use polygon body.

Glad to help.

Comment: Sounds like alpha pixels was the issue (based on his comments above).